# Updating values of child if their parents is updated in a single table php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **person** table with `PersonId`,`FatherId` fields.

```
| PersonId |  FatherId    |
| 1        |      0       | 
| 2        |      1       | 
| 3        |      1       |  
| 4        |      2       |  
| 5        |      3       |   
| 6        |      2       |  
| 7        |      6       |   
| 8        |      7       |
```

If I update personId 2 then all 2,4,6,7,8 should be updated pls suggest a solution.

Comment: Hint:  `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Comment: If update 4 then child of 4(Suppose 9) again child of 9(Suppose 10) so on.. will be updated

Comment: 'Update'? How might you update '2'

Answer (score 2):

This is not feasible in MySQL. Triggers are not allowed to update the same table.

With MySQL it has to be done by application itself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So, in case you'd like to manually do it, use this.

```
UPDATE person SET FatherId = NEWIDVALUE 
WHERE FatherId = OLDVALUE;
-- now update the actual id
UPDATE person SET PersonId = NEWIDVALUE
WHERE PersonId = OLDVALUE
LIMIT 1; -- if your Id values for person are indeed unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with creating triggers before updating  the table.

`CREATE
    TRIGGER 'trigger_name' BEFORE/AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
    ON 'database.table'
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
         - trigger body
     //write what you want to update here.
         END;`

If you want to update the same table with same value as personId for 2, then

```
UPDATE Person set  PersonId = 3 where PersonId IN(2,4,6,7,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look's like you want to update all records on hierarchy basis. For example,suppose if you are assigning an attribute to someone, all child of that person would inherit the same attribute. If correct than you must need to go with PHP solution, use of Trigger in mysql may be some tricky. You can try this one,

**Assumption : You want to assign subfamily to a person.**

```
 <?php

// To manage heierchy data for subfamily
$subfamily_id = '100';
$person_id = '2'; // In your case

$array[] = $person_id;   
$arr = [];

// Do-while loop to assign Subfamily in heierchy
    do {
        foreach($array as $key => $val){
            $sql = 'SELECT person_id FROM person WHERE father_id = "'.$val.'" AND '.$subfamily.' = 0';
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($data as $k => $v){
                $arr[] = $v['person_id'];
            }
            $sql_query = "UPDATE person SET ".$subfamily." = ".$subfamily_id." WHERE father_id = ".$val.' AND '.$subfamily.' = 0';
            $statement = $conn->prepare($sql_query);
            $statement->execute();
        } 
        unset($array);
        $array = $arr;
        unset($arr);
    } 
    while (count($array) > 0);

// Assign Subfamily to individual
$sql_next = "UPDATE person SET ".$subfamily.' = '.$subfamily_id." WHERE person_id = ".$person_id;
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql_next);
$statement->execute();
```